# SSH JumpServer with ProxyJump and Signed SSH Keys by a Certificate Authority

Tags: ssh, centos, certificate, certificate-authority

I want to achieve the following:

- Connect from a Public SSH Server to a Private SSH Server via a Tunnel
- Ideally, this is done comfortably via the "ProxyJump" option for the SSH client

I have the following setup:

- JumpServer (let's call it server_a)

  - A CentOS 7 Server in AWS, publicly reachable from my IP address. TCP/22 is allowed.
- Destination Server (let's call it server_b)

  - A second CentOS 7 Server in AWS, in a Private Subnet, accessible from the JumpServer on Port TCP/22

So the most comfortable way for me would be to use the command ssh server_b and it automatically creates a Tunnel through server_a and connects to server_b.

I don't have any Public Keys stored on any of those servers. Instead, I've copied the Public Key of a Certificate Authority and Trusted this Certificate Authority on both Servers. After signing my Public Key, I can log in to the JumpServer and with SSH-Agent, I can connect with my signed Key to the Destination Server. So the CA setup seems to work.

However, connecting via a Tunnel through the JumpServer, I can't reach the Destination Server. The error message I'm getting is

```
user@local ~ % ssh server_b
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': *********
channel 0: open failed: administratively prohibited: open failed
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Let's have a look at ~/.ssh/config on my local computer:

```
Host server_b
  User centos
  HostName 10.1.2.3
  ProxyJump server_a
  #ProxyCommand ssh -A -W %h:%p server_a

Host server_a
  User centos
  HostName 1.2.3.4
```

Let's have a deeper look at the SSHD Config on the JumpServer (server_a):

```
[root@ip-1-2-3-4 ssh]# grep -v "^#" sshd_config | grep -v "^$"
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 5
AuthenticationMethods publickey
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
GatewayPorts yes
X11Forwarding no
PermitOpen any
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 2
PermitTunnel yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers centos root
TrustedUserCAKeys        /etc/ssh/ca.pub
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/principals/%u
RevokedKeys              /etc/ssh/revoked_keys
```

The Principals and all work fine because I can log in directly to this server with my signed key.

Now let's look at the SSHD Config on the Destination Server (server_b):

```
[root@ip-10-1-2-3 ~]# grep -v "^$" /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep -v "^#"
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 5
AuthenticationMethods publickey
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
UsePAM yes
AllowTCPForwarding yes
PermitOpen any
X11Forwarding no
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 2
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
Subsystem sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers centos root
TrustedUserCAKeys        /etc/ssh/ca.pub
AuthorizedPrincipalsFile /etc/ssh/principals/%u
RevokedKeys              /etc/ssh/revoked_keys
```

On the JumpServer (server_a), I'm getting the following additional **logs** for the SSHD:

```
May 29 09:59:35 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal sshd[9246]: Postponed publickey for centos from 4.1.2.3 port 45978 ssh2 [preauth]
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal sshd[9246]: Accepted publickey for centos from 4.1.2.3 port 45978 ssh2: RSA-CERT ID vault-ldap-11223344-ae1ace4c904549c9fc104e96167162421d017b3f50459926571689878920a6d4 (serial 1970299968302716519) CA RSA SHA256:xvm7NsWz8XrR4fZZ4kp0RmKfgJkrMIme2PB59/7+GB0
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Created slice User Slice of centos.
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd-logind[544]: New session 124 of user centos.
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Started Session 124 of user centos.
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal sshd[9246]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user centos by (uid=0)
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal sshd[9249]: refused local port forward: originator 127.0.0.1 port 65535, target 10.1.2.3 port 22
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal sshd[9246]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user centos
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd-logind[544]: Removed session 124.
May 29 09:59:37 ip-1-2-3-4.eu-central-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Removed slice User Slice of centos.
```

The Destination Server (server_b) doesn't have any logs at all regarding this connection attempt.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I've set SELinux to Permissive with setenforce 0 and cleared all the IPTables rules. Another Firewall is not set up. This is the default CentOS 7 AMI from the AWS Marketplace without any additional configuration with the exception above (sshd config)

This whole procedure works when I add my Public Key to both the server's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file but the purpose of this setup is to use signed keys with the CA.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: "Additional limitations on the validity and use of user certificates may be specified through certificate options.  A certificate option may disable features of the SSH session". Maybe it depends on how the certificates were made? Including the CA

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well and needed to add 'permit-port-forwarding' to the certificate extensions.